# Grails - Retrieving fresh instance from database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Can you force the DomainClass.get(id) functionality in Grails to pull a fresh instance from the database rather then using the local copy retrieved previously in the session?

I would like to compare if a property of the instance has changed:

**Example**:

```
    def myInstance = MyClass.get(params.id)
    myInstance.properties = params.data // updates the instance, but does not save it

    // stuff happens

    def myDbInstance = MyClass.get(params.id) // would like this to  pull a fresh copy from the database, unchanged to allow for comparison
    if(myDbInstance.value != myInstance.value) {
        // do something if has changed
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [`getPersistentValue()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getPersistentValue.html) and [`isDirty()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/isDirty.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use the [refresh()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html) method to force an instance to reload from the database.

Answer (score 0):

In case we want to compare the fields updated in view to the ones that are already available in the database, `refresh()` would update the instance that is yet to be saved in the database.
In that case `getPersistentValue('field_name')` on the instance would fetch the value in database and can be used for comparisons.

If there is `employeeAllocationInstance` already available in controller's update action for e.g., 
and we want to compare the updated fields lets say `jan` allocation
then

`existing_allocation = EmployeeAllocation.get(employeeAllocationInstance.id)`

would have updated the values in `employeeAllocationInstance` so we can do

`existing_allocation?.getPersistentValue('jan')?.value` to get the value that is stored in database (which is yet to be updated)